Does io_getevents(3) handles EINTR (Interrupted system call) implicitly?
Looking at the manual of io_getevents(2), it is clear that API returns error code EINTR
ERRORS         top
       EFAULT Either events or timeout is an invalid pointer.

       EINTR  Interrupted by a signal handler; see signal(7).

       EINVAL ctx_id is invalid.  min_nr is out of range or nr is out of
              range.

       ENOSYS io_getevents() is not implemented on this architecture.

And in case of using this API from libaio then :
Note also that the
       libaio wrapper does not follow the usual C library conventions
       for indicating errors: on error it returns a negated error number
       (the negative of one of the values listed in ERRORS).

I suppose io_getevents(3) is such a libaio wrapper. But on this page it is not mentioned
that this method returns EINTR at all.
ERRORS
  EINVAL
   If ctx is invalid, if min_nr is out of range, if nr is out of range, if when is out of range.
  EFAULT
   If any of the memory specified to is invalid.

and it is not mentioned if this API return negated error numbers.
RETURN VALUES:

May return 0 if no events are available and the timeout specified by when has elapsed, where when == NULL specifies an infinite timeout. Note that the timeout pointed to by when is relative and will be updated if not NULL and the operation blocks. Will fail with ENOSYS if not implemented.

This seems to be backed by the aio_getevents that eventually calls _body_io_syscall
#define _body_io_syscall(sname, args...)    \
{                                           \
    int ret, saved_errno;                   \
    saved_errno = errno;                    \
    ret= syscall(__NR_##sname, ## args);    \
    if (ret < 0) {                          \
        ret = -errno;                       \
        errno = saved_errno;                \
    }                                       \
    return ret;                             \
}

But in practice I've noticed that io_getevents(3) return negated error numbers. It also
return EINTR in case call is interrupted.
Does anyone has idea why there is discrepancy in the documentation of io_getevents(3).
It seems to me that documentation of io_getevents(3) is not updated but io_getevents(2) is reliable. Do I get that right?

There also seems to be a typo in the title of the io_getevents(3) manpage where it misspells io_pgetevents as aio_pgetevents.
